# Magento - show overlay with success message in admin controller

Tags: magento, button, controller, overlay

I have custom module and button in magento admin. In controller I get some information from magento and on click I want to show this information in overlay. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-popup-dialog/ - default magento popup window

Answer (score 1):

For success:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($successMessage);
```

For error:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it, but more important is how to create overlay.